# ejs render with Node.js and socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, ejs

I'm beginning to use Node.js and i've choosen my template engine, which is ejs. My app uses socket.io and on a particular request, it tries to render an ejs file and emit back to the client. The ejs file is rendered beautifully when its a single ejs file without include, but when i try to include another ejs file, it crashes with the following message: "Error: filename option is required for includes".
Note, that

```
  app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render(__dirname+'/views/main/index',{});
   });
```

works just fine, even if index.ejs contains <% include something %>.
My other code partial, which is not working if index.ejs has include (without include it works):

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    fs.readFile('/views/main/index', 'utf8', function (err, template) {
       var content = ejs.render(template,{
                            data:data
                            },function(err,result){
                            console.log(result);
    });
});
```

Here is a example ejs:

```
<% include list_header %> 
<span>random content</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use includes with `ejs.render()` you also [need to pass the `filename` option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs#includes):

```
var content = ejs.render(template, {
  data     : data,
  filename : '/views/main/index'
});
```

(`filename` needs to be the full path of your main template; in your code you're using `/views/main/index` so I used that)

If you regularly need to render the same template I would advise using [`ejs.compile()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs#usage).

Comment: Thank You kind Sir, Your answer works perfectly! It's really wierd (in the good way) for me to experience unconditionally helpfulness, so i've to get use to it! Thanks again!